# Replace GCE fluentd-cloud-logging with my own container

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We are using kubernetes provided by "Google Container Engine" with enabled "Cloud Logging" feature. But we need to configure fluentd for our application (add more information about application what runs in container).

I can't find any information how I can add my configs to logging agent provided by google and any way to replace it with my owned container.

Does exists any way how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an easy way to customize the fluentd configuration in Google Container Engine (and if you try to customize it, your changes will be lost if a node gets replaced by the instance group manager or during a node upgrade).

If you want to run a custom fluentd configuration, you should disable cloud logging on your cluster and then run your own fluentd container on each node with the configuration that you need for your application.

Until [Daemon Sets](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/admin/daemons.md) are available, the easiest way to run one pod per host is to assign the pod a host port and then create a replication controller with more replicas than you have hosts.

Comment: Thanks! But i found other way to do this. I build docker container based on google container and replace fluentd configuration in it with mine. Next I changed container name for fluend-gcp that used by saltstack script for instance template for node provisioning, and I changed saltstack url in kube-env of template settings to my archive url. Now I have custom google-fluentd container for my nodes.

Comment: Did you modify the saltstack config on each of your nodes?

Comment: I modify only vars in kube-env metadata for  SALT_TAR_HASH  and SALT_TAR_URL to my url with modified saltstack archive.

Comment: Nice! In my answer I said there wouldn't be an easy way and while your solution works quite well, I certainly don't consider it straightforward. :)